# dev.new() launch to second monitor

Tags: r, windows, plot, ess

I am wondering if anyone is aware of a way to call `dev.new()` and have the resulting frame launch to a second monitor by default.  I'm running R through ESS under Windows 7. It defaults to upper right corner of my primary monitor.

UPDATE

`dev.new(xpos=1930, ypos=65)` will launch the plot window to upper left corner of my secondary monitor.

I would still be interested in how to set `xpos` and `ypos` under `device`, either per session, per script, or globally.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `getOption("device")` and `Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_")`. There should be your device number. I am on linux, so can't say what windowZ call these, but I get a number. If the default one is 1, than if I set it to 2, i get it on the external monitor.

Comment: So what exactly are you saying one should do? Are these numbers supposed to go into `dev.new()`, like `dev.new(2)`? Didn't do anything on my Win 10 machine.

Comment: Thanks hike.  `getOption` got me to a call per device (updated above).  However, `Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_")` returns an empty `chr`.

Comment: @joeln I do not get it. How can you use `getOption` to specify the device? Can you please post some code of it?